# Replace method of String does not Change the String

Tags: c#, string, immutability

I try to replace the file name which contains "TEMPDOCUMENTLIBRARY" with "SHAREDDOCS" in the 
**docs (Typed Dataset)**. But somehow it does not replace it at all.
What's wrong ?

```
for (int index = 0; index < docs.Document.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    if (docs.Document[index].FileName.Contains("TEMPDOCUMENTLIBRARY"))
    {
         docs.Document[index].BeginEdit();
         docs.Document[index].FileName.Replace("TEMPDOCUMENTLIBRARY", "SHAREDDOCS");
         docs.Document[index].EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable (meaning that the value of a given string *never changes*). Functions like `Substring` and `Replace` return *new* strings that represent the original string with the desired operations performed.

In order to achieve what you want, you need this:

```
docs.Document[index].FileName = 
      docs.Document[index].FileName.Replace("TEMPDOCUMENTLIBRARY", "SHAREDDOCS");
```

Comment: Quick question: You and I understand that strings are immutable, however is it really necessary to have that understanding in order to work with simplistic methods like `String.Replace` or `String.Substring`? The function returns the result you want which is basically all anyone *using* the method should need to know, right?

Comment: @M.Babcock - Apparently it is.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - I could care less who got the answer, my question is more general then that. We have a lot of experts here on SO that understand what happens under the covers in .NET, but when it comes to simple questions like this one, is it really necessary to force language and education on them that isn't necessary for a general user to have in order to just *use* the language?

Comment: @M.Babcock: I believe that it's beneficial for users to understand *why* methods work the way they do so that they'll understand more than "If I do X, I get Y." If they know why X produces Y, then they might be able to figure out how to get Z on their own instead of coming back to ask an incremental question. I'm curious why you think  a greater understanding is a bad thing? It's not as if I wrote a dissertation on immutability.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - I didn't say it was a bad thing; I just know in my experience, users tend to see "Strings are immutable" but they read "Strings are *blah*". I've spent countless hours writing technical docs for users that frankly have no interest in understanding what happens under the covers just for them to skim it and ask me 10 minutes later about something that I'd already written about. I can guarantee we have a large number of people here that will do the same thing.

Comment: @M.Babcock: SO is aimed at developers, not end users. There is an expectation that a developer will want to know *what* works and *why*, even if it's not true for any given individual. I'm curious, though, on what basis you'd make such a guarantee; in my three years on SO, I've dealt with *far* more people who want a genuine understanding of what it is they're writing rather than a recipe of what buttons to push. In any case, if you feel that such information is unhelpful, you're obviously free to exclude it from your own answers.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - The end users in my case are developers whose jobs depend on knowing the material and still have no interest in understanding it. Regardless, my point is not to degrade your approach (in fact I enjoy picking up upvotes from people that take more time while providing the same answer), it is more that the documentation provided on the subject included the detail needed to answer the question yet I was curious why you felt it necessary to go beyond. Now I know why. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @M.Babcock - I would suggest that developers who "have no interest in understanding" why things work the way they do are not good developers!

Answer (score 2):

[`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) does not replace in place. Try:

```
docs.Document[index].FileName = docs.Document[index].FileName.Replace("TEMPDOCUMENTLIBRARY", "SHAREDDOCS");
```

Notice in the documentation (linked above) that it returns the result of the replace.